# Bootstrap-table.js altura dinámica

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Buenas estoy probando el plugin **bootstrap-table** y estoy queriendo hacer que la altura de la tabla sea dinámica según el contenedor en donde se ubica o mejor dicho que sea variable de acuerdo a la resolución del usuario.

[image: Ejemplo]

En la imagen se puede apreciar que la tabla tiene habilitada un scrollbar, esto porque en el código yo indique la altura de datos **data-height** que es de 500 y cuando la visualización de los registros supera esa propiedad se habilita la barra de desplazamiento.

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped " 
data-toggle="table" 
data-search="true"
data-show-toggle="true"
data-pagination="false"
data-height="500"
data-show-columns="true"
data-toolbar="#toolbar">
```

Al tener la tabla una barra de desplazamiento vertical no hace falta que se habilite la barra de desplazamiento del navegador, pero, ¿que pasa si la resolución del usuario es menor? - se habilita el scroll del navegador y eso no se es estético.

Por eso, necesito que la altura sea dinámica ya que el usuario puede tener una resolución diferente y así lograr que la altura de la tabla siempre cubra la totalidad de la página.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con CSS

```
table
{
  max-height:500px;
  height:auto;
}
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que necesito es que la atura sea variable. Si el usuario   tiene una pantalla con una resolución superior que la altura de la tabla abarque toda la pantalla y si su resolución es inferior que también muestre igual.

Answer (score 0):

La solución esta en sustituir en el atributo `height` la unidad `%` por la unidad `vh`: esto quiere decir que la tabla ocupará el 100% del espacio disponible en sentido vertical sin importar desde cuál dispositivo se visualice la misma.

```
.table {
     height: 100vh;
}
```